# How can I get rid of already initialized constant warnings when requiring files inside env.rb?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I require some files in `features/support/env.rb` as:

```
['/helpers/*', '/pages/*', '/models/*'].each do |path|
  Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + path].each { |file| require file }
end
```

(I do it as I'd want to create test users and some other stuff before any of my tests are run.)

But it seems those files are then loaded by Cucumber using `load` as I get a ton of warnings like when Cucumber loads them:

```
/home/andrey/dev/project/features/support/models/my_class.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant MyClass::MY_CONSTANT
```

when scenarios start. How can I get rid of those warnings?

Comment: `require` should load file only once. I think problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Cucumber [loads it using `load`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/f74a8dad3e8ff1b1e9fe7762369266817f229a8f/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb#L137), not `require`

Comment: Maybe you can do what you want to do with your helpers and models in the cucumber Before hook?

Comment: @Alexis No, setup is quiet long so I don't want to do it before each scenario/feature

Comment: @AndreyBotalov https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#running-a-before-hook-only-once ?

Comment: @Alexis you can post it as an answer

Comment: @AndreyBotalov ok, now when I posted my answer, I'd like to know if it was of any help to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your code in a `silence_warnings` block:

```
silence_warnings do
  ['/helpers/*', '/pages/*', '/models/*'].each do |path|
    Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + path].each { |file| require file }
  end
end
```

There's probably a better way to to whatever it is that you're trying to do, in a way that will play nice with your test framework, but the code above should handle your immediate question.

Comment: First time files are required by code inside question and your answer so silence_warnings won't help. Second time they are loaded using `load` using Cucumber itself and at this time warning is generated

Answer (score 0):

You probably can setup your helpers and models in a cucumber Before hook.

The recommended way to run a before hook only once is to use a global variable, so:

```
Before do 
  if !$already_required
    ['/helpers/*', '/pages/*', '/models/*'].each do |path|
      Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + path].each { |file| require file }
    end
    $already_required = true 
  end 
end
```

(https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#running-a-before-hook-only-once)